# internal mechanical drive vs external SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I recently got into a debate about about what would provide the best performance for booting an operating system, from an internal mechanical disk vs an mSATA enclosure attached with USB 3.0. His belief was that because a SSD has a better read/write rate it would be better. My thoughts are that because it is booting from an external device that it might cause latency which would might negate any benefits from the increase read/write time, or cause other problems.

- The same computer would be used for both.
- pretend that both hard drives contain the exact same OS and operate the absolute best they can.
- We understand that an internal SSD would out perform either one.

Comment: From my personnal experience, booting Windows 8.1 on an external SSD with USB 3.0 (cheap adapter) is much faster than with an internal drive. Data transfer rate is similar (~100Mo/s with big files) but since it's much more faster with random read/write, it's faster to boot and more responsive.

Comment: Aye. The key here is that sequential read/write speed is nice when you copy a big movie or some iso files, but the OS uses a lot of small reads. In that area an SSD shines and the bandwidth limits are not a limitation. (Latency should hurt some though, so external eSATA or external SAS would be faster then external USB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best SSD drives provide much faster performance than the best mechanical HDD. All you need then it to ensure that the I/O path to the SSD is faster than the maximum throughput of the mechanical drive and it will perform faster. Ideally this is an eSATA interface but USB 3.0 will do to. It's a bus, so that performance is shared between devices but it has more than  enough for a single drive.

You are right that there is a latency hit for an external disk versus an internal one but it is truly minimal, particularly with eSATA. The other great thing about SSDs is that they are random access and perform comparatively better than a mechanical disk when reading multiple streams which occurs during OS boot because so many files and programs have to be loaded.

Comment: I don't understand a lot of intricate details with computer hardware, but your saying usb's share data transfer? In that case if another usb device was plugged in this would halve the transfer rate? I ask because the person I was talking to is going to go on a trip soon and wanted to use the external drive with OS to edit their videos, so assuming they will use a secondary hard drive to hold the video files will that cause problems?

Comment: USB stands for Universal Serial Bus. All devices on the same bus share the bandwidth but its not allocated meaning they get what the use at a given time. So if you have 2 devices they don't simply get 3 Gb/s each. If they both try to transfer simultaneously, then the total will max out at 6 GB/s (theoretical not actual) but how it is divided is *kind of* random.

Comment: @user304176 - Regarding the video part, I can tell you its too complex to answer. We would need to know the speed of the drive, resolution and bit-rate of the video to even guess. This I know because I spent 9 years working on video special effect software and my job was to ensure the maximum performance from processing and storage subsystems. Plus, the application has an *enormous* impact on how I/O performs.

Comment: `The best SATA drives provide` did you mean `the best SSDs`?

Comment: As to sharing USB bandwidth: This is true unless you put the devices on different USB controllers. In many laptops you will find multiple USB controllers, each connected to several ports. (E.g. often the older USB2 controller and a dedicated chip with an USB3 controller. In that case bandwith between the USB3 connected drive and an USB2 connected drives/mouse/keyboard/whatever is not shared).

Comment: @Hennes - Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't that simple.  There are different interfaces an external drive can be using, USB 2.0, USB 3.0, eSATA, thunderbolt, firewire, etc..

As long as the speed of the connection is fast enough for full throughput (such as USB 3.0 at 6 gigabit/sec) the SSD should be faster than the mechanical drive because the biggest thing that slows down a hard drive while booting is all the random access.  The drive has to physically move parts internally before reading the data.  The SSD has nothing to move.

Comment: So because he wanted to attach using USB 3.0 it would preform better? I know SSD are faster then mechanical but I was worried that because it would be plugged in somewhere besides the internal sata that it might confuse the system and cause latency.

Comment: It's possible, but it would be hardware / OS / driver specific.  You'd really have to benchmark for sure. I would still surmise that physically moving inside the drive would be slower than any overhead.  There are drivers for the internal drive as well.

Comment: Also worth noting is that sustained throughput would matter for some operations, and USB3 is not as great at sustained as eSATA or Firewire...

Comment: Would video editing be sustained throughput?