# External SSD vs. Internal standard HD for speed?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I am using a laptop for gaming because I am not able to build a desktop currently. I was thinking about getting an external SSD for the speed, but I was wondering if it would be worth it, as I am not sure if an external SSD through USB 3.0 would be faster than the internal HD. Does anyone know if the external SSD would be faster? I'm thinking in general, not for a specific HD/SSD comparison.
Also, I did look at the other question posted below, but they were talking about booting an operating system, while I am looking at storing games and programs that I will be using. As I understand it, USB 3.0 may not be as great for the sustained usage I would assume gaming would require.
[internal mechanical drive vs external SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/725274/internal-mechanical-drive-vs-external-ssd)

Edit: Here I am looking at an actual USB SSD drive rather than a SATA SSD in a USB enclosure. For example, a MyPassport or similar SSD external mass storage device. However, many of the points in the current answers are still valid. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In theory it would not work:

- Internal SATA speed is likely to be 6 Gbps, and USB 3.0 is slower than that.
- external USB enclosure is likely to introduce further delays (SATA to USB, then USB to memory) as well as limiting protocol capabilities (e.g. by default the USB drive won't have write back cache, what Windows calls optimize for speed, but write through or optimize for fast removal. At a lower level you lose SMART and, I think, write queue optimization).

In practice, you might get  better performance in sustained reads, when the SSD overtakes the mechanical disk cache capability. The mechanic is not always capable of keeping up with the SATA interface, and 6 Gbps is only the maximum talking speed between electronics: the platter may have been left behind.

Run a disk read speed test with large data blocks and see. Values below 4-5 Gbps might indicate a SSD would do better.

On the other hand this is only true if your game does read lots of sequential data. Random reads are probably best left to the internal disk.

Comment: In this case I am looking at an actual USB external drive rather than an SSD in an enclosure. I did not think about possible confusion there. So in this instance it would be direct USB, but I do understand your point about the delays there, and also with the lack of caching.

Comment: A modern 7200 rpm HDD will usually reach 120-130 MB/s in sustained *purely sequential* I/O, so from that point of view, even 1.5 Gb/s SATA is quite enough. Even more so because virtually no storage workloads are purely sequential in nature, and any random I/O component will reduce the performance when the drive needs to seek.

Answer (score 15):

Using an SSD in a USB 3.0 enclosure is totally possible, but it carries some pretty hefty disadvantages that make it rather unsuitable for what you're wanting to do:

- TRIM does not work over USB, so an SSD will slow down over time and will wear faster.  Also NCQ is not supported, which may slow down reads.
- All USB data storage devices are treated as removable by Windows, so you do not get read/write caching and buffering the way you do for internal drives.
- USB is a shared bus, so the 5GBits/sec speed is shared amongst all other USB connected devices.  SATA is 6GBits/sec *per port*.
- USB uses PIO for data transfers whereas SATA uses DMA.  That means your main CPU has to do all the work of moving the data across the bus. A constant, sustained load can slow your whole computer down.
- *Installing* some applications to a USB device can often turn that device into a system dependency (meaning Windows might throw errors or display other odd behavior if the device is not present) -- even if you aren't using that application.
- Some applications won't even let you install them to a USB drive.

Those are just the disadvantages I could think of.  If you can live with these disadvantages, then by all means go for it.  It will (mostly) work fine.  However, if I were you, I'd swap out the internal HDD for the SSD and put the internal drive into the enclosure instead.  Note that you'd have to reinstall Windows this way, because Windows will not boot from a USB drive.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am talking about an actual USB external drive rather than a standard SSD in an enclosure. But I do see your point about the drive slowing down the entire computer. I have noticed this with an external USB spinning disk drive that I used on an older laptop when my internal drive got full.

Comment: Also, I wish I could mark this as an answer as well as the other, because while the other was more of a direct answer, this one answered a few other questions and had detailed points that helped out as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install the SSD as your internal drive and use the internal drive as the external one?

I would not suggest using the external drive for gaming purposes as there are a lot of things that can make usage unstable. Depending on what other types of devices you use on the same USB hub. USB 3.0 has a theoretical speed of 480 Mbps which is 60 MBps shared for all devices. This is greater than most spinning drives, but I don't believe you will get this speed over a prolonged period of time.

Comment: That is incorrect, @Mogget. You are thinking of USB 2.0. USB 3.0 has a speed of 5Gbit/sec, which is very close to SATA's 6GBits/sec. An SSD connected to a USB 3.0 port would be nearly as fast as if it were internal.

Comment: In this case I am looking at an actual USB external drive rather than a standard SATA SSD in an enclosure. If I had the money I would probably clone my HDD over to an SSD of the same or greater size and be done with it like you suggest.

Comment: @WesSayeed Sorry, I read the wrong RFC. Then I agree, the speed would be more than sufficient. I still believe though that there is a lot of issues using USB as a transport for data to and from an SSD. Most of them pointed out by me or other posts in this thread. Thanks for clearing up the mistake I made.