# Extending C drive with external storage

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, ssd

I have a very specific use case in which I have a internal SSD that has 120GB of free space after a fresh install of windows 10 and manually removal of as much bloat as possible (I also compressed the entire drive). I also have a 128GB usb thumbdrive for storage however I'm in need of the ability to download a 200GB file, which unfortunately is assisted by a program that pre-calculates the disk space available.

That being said I'm looking for some method to have windows recognize my USB drive not as a USB drive but as the C drives storage, turning my 120GB/128GB of separate storage space into 248GB of usable space.

Is the above possible?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/978815/external-ssd-vs-internal-standard-hd-for-speed explains some of the problems you would face in doing so.

Comment: I hate to be negative when asking for help but I don't think either of you understood the question I want to install a program across two drives and still be functional.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to clarify this. @harry

Comment: Check out [Storage Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces).

Comment: When people don't understand your question, it falls to you to improve the question to make it more clear, something we've pointed out already here.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's probably **not** possible to *install* it. Even if you broke the file into pieces, or had someone do that for you, e.g. [using 7-Zip](https://www.newsgroupreviews.com/7-zip-split-archive.html), you'd need more contiguous disk space to install it.

However, larger SSD's are available, e.g. this [240 GB drive for ~US$32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076XXMJZH).

Comment: Agree. I'm afraid to say this is a clear case of "you need a bigger drive" They are **cheap** these days. You don't want to know what I paid for a 1TB SSD 5 years ago.